# Put Password on using the Internet

Tags: windows-xp, internet, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make it as difficult as possible to connect to the Internet from my “work computer”?](https://superuser.com/questions/32728/how-can-i-make-it-as-difficult-as-possible-to-connect-to-the-internet-from-my-wo)

I have a computer at work and I don't want other people to use it for Internet.
How can I set a password for the internet?

Comment: Various: http://superuser.com/questions/81364/lan-only http://superuser.com/questions/15425/av-route http://superuser.com/questions/32728/self-control

Comment: why not just set a password on your windows user and just switch-user or log out when you're using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "Content advisor" to block all sites. Then when you enter your password it enables access to websites as usual.

This is far from the perfect solution, but comes closest to what you want...

Read this for more information/a howto:
http://www.wikihow.com/Restrict-Web-Browsing-Using-Internet-Explorer

PS.
there are a lot of ways around this solution, you would be better off to put passwords on your pc, and always lock the computer when you leave the workstation.