# windows xp - Disable internet access but leave LAN working solution - also blocks inbound?

Tags: windows-xp

I found Stefan Seidel's Answer for:
Disable internet access but leave LAN working
at: [Disable internet access but leave LAN working](https://superuser.com/questions/586517/disable-internet-access-but-leave-lan-working)

I found that the command line entry to disable internet access was required again after each re-boot, which is fine by me.

However, what I was originally trying to do, and ensure, was to prevent external (to my router) internet access to this particular XP machine AND maintain internal (LAN) connectivity between it and other PCs on my home LAN getting their IPs from said router, which is an old Linksys WRT54G V8.

I thought it would be best to ask Stefan to clarify whether his solution would be an effective inbound internet IP blocker, however, as a newly registered superuser.com user, I don't see a method of contacting him directly.

Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Give that XP machine a static IP address in the subnet range your other PCs have and leave the Gateway IP address blank. This is what you are looking for, that does not change on reboot.

[How to]
R/click the network icon, choose properties, you are in the general tab now.
Notice the protocol entries in the middle box, choose the last one (Internet protocol IP4) but do not uncheck the box. Choose properties button, enter an appropriate IP address in your subnet.
say, 192.168.1.250. Enter 255.255.255.0 as subnet mask, Leave Gateway blank.
Enter DNS address, either from entry listed on other PCs using ipconfig /all command, or use 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 (Google DNS).
These are the basics.

If you need screen to screen help, let me know. (Your router may need an exclusion range too, to be safe.)

Dave

Comment: My answer takes into account your question, as stated " prevent external (to my router) internet access to this particular XP machine". Since internet communication is a two way street, disabling inbound internet access also precludes outbound communications. Maybe what you are really looking for is a firewall product, other than XP firewall. Say, Outpost or such.

Comment: Although you don't need a Google DNS address, if you don't already put in a local DNS IP address, it will become useful when you finally allow internet access by adding the routers local IP address in the gateway fields.

Comment: Dave ... I thought I might get an e-mail notification of your responses ... I did not ... thank you for the advice ... I will implement and test ... also, cutting off two-way internet is not a problem, I only need local LAN connectivity over TCP / IP ... Kevin