# How can I block a program's access to my local network, but not the internet?

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall

I want to allow a program to access the web but not any computers on my local network.

I found an answer here:

[How can I block a program from accessing the Internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/363540/how-can-i-block-a-program-from-accessing-the-internet)

But I think that assumes you want to block all access, not just local network.

Then, there's this:

https://superuser.com/a/363553/18135

But I need to be able to use localhost for other reasons.

Here's another two asking the reverse, but I don't see anything in those answers that can be reversed:

[allowing local network access while blocking internet access](https://superuser.com/questions/81364/allowing-local-network-access-while-blocking-internet-access)

[Disable internet access but leave LAN working](https://superuser.com/questions/586517/disable-internet-access-but-leave-lan-working)

[How can I restrict windows 7 to only use the local subnet, but block the internet](https://superuser.com/questions/345758/how-can-i-restrict-windows-7-to-only-use-the-local-subnet-but-block-the-interne?rq=1)

All I want to do is block a *specific program* from accessing local area network while still allowing internet access to it. Is this possible?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/345758/how-can-i-restrict-windows-7-to-only-use-the-local-subnet-but-block-the-interne?rq=1) just apply the rules in question to the programs installed on your machine to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks, as I read through that, I don't see a clear answer to do the reverse that I'm asking. From what I can tell, the guides allow for network and not internet, but not internet and not network. Maybe not possible? Or maybe I'm not experienced enough in this area to tell. I'm hoping for a clear SuperUser answer on this. :)

Comment: You can do it with a "custom" outbound rule in windows firewall, only allow the program to use port 80

Comment: @Moab I never thought of that. If you can post some directions as an answer, I'll be happy to reward you with the correct answer.